# SQL check for values after a condition in case

Tags: sql, postgresql, chat

I'm querying a dataset that contains messages sent by a chatbot and by agents.

I need to identify abandoned chats, a chat is considered abandoned if the customer ends the chat before the assigned agent writes a message.

Dataset Example:
dialog id is the chat id, sequence is the order of messages sent.

| Dialogid | Sequence | Message | sentby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1D | 1 | You are now chatting to agent1 | agent |
| 1D | 2 | Hi | agent |
| 1D | 3 | How can I help? | agent |
| 2D | 1 | You are now chatting to agent2 | agent |

The message 'You are now chatting to' is an automated message so if the agent has not sent a message after that then the chat would be abandoned, so in the above example only dialogid 2D would be considered abandoned.

My current query counts 'you are now chatting to' as a message sent by the agent when really it should look for any messages sent after the 'You are now chatting to' message.

Messages sent by the bot also show as sentby 'agent' so i need to identify any messages sent by a human agent that appear after 'you are now chatting to' and elminate the bot messages by stating:

```
and not upper(substring(msg_text from 26 for 7)) = 'CHATBOT'
```

Current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT flag1.dialogid, sum(flag1.transferindicator) as sum_transfer, sum(flag1.advisorfirstmsg) as sum_advisorfirstmsg
from (select dialogid, message_time, 
case when ((upper(substring(msg_text from 7 for 49)))= 'TRANSFERRING YOU THROUGH TO SOMEONE WHO CAN HELP.')
or (upper(substring(msg_text for 41)) = 'OK, TYPE YOUR MESSAGE NOW AND PRESS SEND.' )
or (sentby = 'Consumer' and upper(substring(msg_text for 13)) = 'LEAVE MESSAGE')
then 1 else 0 end as transferindicator, 
case when ((upper(substring(msg_text for 24)) = 'YOU ARE NOW CHATTING TO '
    and not upper(substring(msg_text from 25 for 7)) = 'CHATBOT'
    or (upper(substring(msg_text for 25)) = 'YOU ARE NOW CONNECTED TO '
    and not upper(substring(msg_text from 26 for 7)) = 'CHATBOT'
then 1 else 0 end as advisorfirstmsg
from chat.raw_messagerecords
where CAST(message_time at time zone 'UTC' as date) >= current_date -49) as flag1 group by dialogid) as flag2;
```

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some advice on how to best approach this dilemma.

I considered trying to return the sequence number of the message 'You are now chatting to' and sentby 'agent' assigning 1 to advisorfirstmsg if there is any sequence number greater than that for the same dialogid and 0 if not, however I'm struggling to achieve this.

I have tried the query provided and checked how to return a value from a different column based on another column but cant figure out how to incorporate it into a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you abandoned chats:

```
select mr.*
from chat.raw_messagerecords mr
where not exists (
    select tmp.Dialogid
    from chat.raw_messagerecords tmp
    where tmp.Dialogid = mr.Dialogid
    and tmp.message not like 'You are now chatting to %'
    and tmp.sentby = 'agent'
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. The query provided returns all messages that are not like 'you are now chatting to' which includes messages sent by the bot prior to been transferred to an agent. That's my fault, my question was missing some information - messages sent by the bot also show as sentby 'agent'  which is why  I originally excluded these messages with:
`and not upper(substring(msg_text from 25 for 7)) = 'CHATBOT'`

Comment: **Do not** use a comment to supply additional information or respond to to a question. Please update your question with the above additional information. A comment letting the responder know you have updated the question is fine.

Comment: Sorry - the original post has been updated.